# Android: What happens to Async Task return value

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-async-http

What happens to the return value or call to the Aysnc task if the application that has called has finished.

Say i call a network operation in Aysnc task and my UI thread which called it has finished the operation.

My objective is to the save the data that is received in the N/W call, so that i need to re-do a call next time?

Below is the code snippet where In doInBackground() i make a SOAP request and while the request is on, the main UI that had called the Aync task somehow dies/finishes. What will happen to my response? How can i save the response for future use.

```
    Code:

        class SOAPCallAyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(SoapMainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String theResult = "";
        byte[] result = null;

        try {
            result = callSOAPServer();
            theResult = new String(result);
            Log.d("R-Doit in backgound", theResult);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return theResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String theResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(theResult);
        pd.dismiss();
        Log.d("R-Result", theResult);
    }

}
```

Comment: u can save data in post execute of asynctask

Comment: can you share some of your AsyncTask code.?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean. But if you cancel AsyncTask, it finishes it's background work, though `onPostExecute` does not happen.

Comment: you can save the data in any variable,sharedprefrences or in database according to your need and its size in doInBackground or onPostExecute

Comment: @Marius: Will the postexecute still be called if the caller is dead?

Comment: @PramodYadav you should be careful with SharedPreferences in background, since, as per Documentation, `Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time, the last one to call commit wins.`

Comment: @PramodYadav: As Marius said bg write is not preferred. futhermore when the main thread is dead, how can i store/save it?

Comment: @Learner From experience, yes, but I can't find any documentation on that. Though be careful, your app will crash if you try to interact with Activity that is finished. In my app, I simply do 3sec task, and if I pause the Activity that started AsyncTask, execution continues.

Comment: @Learner try saving values in `onPostExecute`. Since `SharedPreferences` don't need `Activity` - only `Context`, you can modify your constructor and save `Context` and create `SharedPreferences` from that `Context` in `onPostExecute`. Though I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: @Marius : Sure will give a try

Answer (score 0):

The `AsyncTask` will complete execution even if the application is closed / destroyed unless the system calls for it to stop executing (which is generally not the case).

You can save the data that was received in the network call in the `SharedPreferences` and then update the UI accordingly whenever the activity is created (or in `onResume()` ) again (if required) by fetching the saved data from the `SharedPreferences`. If you see that no data was fetched during the last `AsyncTask` execution, you can make a new execute request accordingly.

Comment: Do u say that, if I am stroign my data in the PostExecute() method, irrespective of the status of the application still postExecute() will be called. let me try that and get back to u

Comment: @Learner Yeah. It'll still be called.